# User does not exist error when copying user names in Quick Edit view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, quick-edit

I have an excel file with the names of the users in Lastname, Firstname(Location) format. When creating a new item, I copy the name of the user and paste it the people picker field(Name with presence) and it does work without any errors

However, when I use the Quick Edit view and follow the same process, I'm getting User does not exist or is not unique error. Is there some limitation in IE or some issue in AD?

Please suggest.

Note: I'm using IE32bit and SharePoint 2013